# Chrome Extension is showing/hiding

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a small application which will be able to manage Chrome's Extensions. Currently I am able to list all installed extensions and their state (Enabled/Disabled). The problem is that finding out what causes an Extension to be hidden in Extension management UI in Chrome.

Actually, I can't figure out the logic behind when an Extension is showing/hiding in Chrome UI.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean apps? If `isApp` is set to `true` it isn't listed as extension

Comment: No, I mean extensions like Ad-block, lastpass, and so on.

Comment: You can use event listeners to determine when extensions are dis-/enabled: [`chrome.management.onDisabled`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#event-onDisabled) and [`chrome.management.onEnabled`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#event-onEnabled). Is it that what you mean?

Comment: Yes I know. It has been already done. Enabling and Disabling works perfectly but I asked about handling state when Extension is Showing/hiding in Chrome UI.

Comment: Sorry but it wasn't very clear what you meant with UI, I thought of the list in `chrome://chrome/extensions`. So I think I get it now, you mean if the `browserAction` icon is hidden? I have not found any documentation of this behaviour. Seems like there are no event listeners for that. [You could file a report in the issue list](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I have got one more question. Is it even possible to get state extension's icon when Google Chrome is closed - weather it is hidden or not? I do not need to listen if the state of extension icon has been changed.

Comment: I am not aware of that, maybe you should create another question with this specific problem.